# Дублирование контента на html странице

Tags: html, seo

Есть страница, она является адаптивной, но для ее адаптивности приходится дублировать контент, т.е. на мобильной версии показывается один блок информации, а на пк версии показывается другой блок информации, в то время как мобильный блок скрывается (display: none;), и наоборот, получается так что информация в этих блоках идентичная, но она представлена в разном виде.

Например в пк версии определенный блок находится в правой колонке контента, на планшетной в левой колонке, на телефоне колонки пропадают и блок показывается во всю ширину, при этом таких адаптивных блоков очень много, и сверстать это без дублирования контента наверно невозможно.

Но, на дублирование контента очень плохо смотрят поисковики, и возможно даже снижают рейтинг сайта в поиске, а это не есть гуд. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Никогда ничего не слышал о `@media`?

Comment: Я `@media` и использую, это и есть адаптивность! Но, как я писал ранее, на мобильной и пк версиях форма контента слишком разная, и без дублирования (скрытие пк блоков, показа мобильных блоков по определенной ширине) сверстать нельзя.

Comment: Можно. С помощью `js` и `@media`. Но это большой объём работы.

Comment: Например, пк версия - http://joxi.ru/DmBJvz5TwGxLlm, до мобильная версия - http://joxi.ru/Vm6aV9EhDozpPr. Мне кажется тут и с помощью js если не невозможно сделать, то по крайней мере нецелесообразно. А это еще не все адаптивные элементы, их на самом деле еще больше.

Comment: Там еще в совсем мобильной версии верхний блок со странами, переезжает почти в самый низ страницы, как это сделать без дублей (скрыть верхний блок, отобразить нижний) честно не совсем понимаю.

Comment: Те скриншоты что Вы привели не являются чем-то сверхестественным, и не нуждаются в дублировании

Comment: Ваши блоки не меняются в зависимости от устройства, а просто перемещаются, меняют размер и всё. Так что здесь нужен простой и грамотный CSS.

Comment: Приведите пример верстки если хотите и Вам покажут как это делатется

Comment: Как же не меняются, если блок с информацией в мобильной версии становится открывающимся/закрывающимся?

Comment: Также не всегда удается поменять некоторые элементы местами только средствами css, нормально это можно сделать через flexbox order, но не всегда для этого подходит верстка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но, на дублирование контента очень плохо смотрят поисковики, и
>   возможно даже снижают рейтинг сайта в поиске, а это не есть гуд. Как
>   можно решить данную проблему?

Эта проблема давно решена Гугл. Проверьте руководство Гугл **[Разные url](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls)**:

> Аннотации в коде HTML На обычной странице
>   (http://www.example.com/page-1) добавьте следующий код:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" 
href="http://m.example.com/page-1">
```

> На странице для мобильных
>   устройств (http://m.example.com/page-1) используйте следующие
>   атрибуты:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/page-1">
```

> В URL, который размещен на странице мобильного сайта и указывает на 
>   аналог этой страницы с обычным форматированием, необходимо добавить
>   тег rel="canonical".

Answer (score 0):

> "...получается так что информация в этих блоках идентичная, но она
>   представлена в разном виде."
>
> "...Например в пк версии определенный блок находится в правой колонке
>   контента, на планшетной в левой колонке, на телефоне колонки пропадают
>   и блок показывается во всю ширину"

В мобильной и десктопной версии сайта используется один и то же контент, если я правильно понял. Нет разницы где какой блок размещается. Ознакомьтесь со [справкой google][1]

[1]: https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-first-indexing, раздел "Подготовка к индексированию, ориентированному на мобильные устройства".